# GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) CCS/XMPP delivery receipt is not bound to the right session

Tags: android, cloud, google-cloud-messaging, messaging

Our app servers are running in multi-node cluster with each creating an XMPP connection to the GCM CCS/XMPP server with the same account. In each outgoing message to the Android devices, delivery_receipt_requested flag is enabled. The app servers do receive the delivery receipts but they do not always go to the connection through which the message was sent. It looks like GCM server does not do session binding correctly for delivery receipt. Does anybody have experience on this?

Comment: I am having the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416971/gcm-xmpp-delivery-receipt-send-other-machine-and-gcm-closes-connection-when-rece

Comment: please check my answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416971/gcm-xmpp-delivery-receipt-send-other-machine-and-gcm-closes-connection-when-rece/32463658#32463658